# child to parent event emit

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vue-router

wrote a code to emit and receive event from child to parent but instead of receiving event it is showing something else

```js
function (event) {
  var vm = this;
  if (true) {
    var lowerCaseEvent = event.toLowerCase();
    if (lowerCaseEvent !== event && vm._events[lowerCaseEvent]) {
      tip("Event \"" + lowerCaseEvent + "\" is emitted in component " + (formatComponentName(vm)) + " but the handler is registered for \"" + event + "\". " +
        "Note that HTML attributes are case-insensitive and you cannot use " + "v-on to listen to camelCase events when using in-DOM templates. " + "You should probably use \"" + (hyphenate(event)) + "\" instead of \"" + event + "\".");
    }
  }
  var cbs = vm._events[event];
  if (cbs) {
    cbs = cbs.length > 1 ? toArray(cbs) : cbs;
    var args = toArray(arguments, 1);
    var info = "event handler for \"" + event + "\"";
    for (var i = 0, l = cbs.length; i < l; i++) {
      invokeWithErrorHandling(cbs[i], vm, args, vm, info);
    }
  }
  return vm
}
```

checked all the codes online for same

```html
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <p>{{name}}</p>
    <Login v-on:datam="update($emit)"></Login>
  </div>
</template>
```

```js
import Login from './views/Login.vue'

export default {
  name: 'app',
  components: {
    Login
  },
  methods: {
    update: function (ok1) {
      this.name = ok1;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please make sure to format your code properly, try to publishing both your parent and child component in a playground like this: https://jsfiddle.net/Le5zw6av/1/

Answer (score 0):

You can emit event using external event file. so it'll be access for all your components.

Firstly we should create a file. name event.js

```
import Vue from 'vue';

export default new Vue({
    data: {

    }
});
```

After that you should import that event.js to your components

```
import Event from "../event.js";
```

Then you can emit an event on your component like below

```
methods() {
  function yourMethod(){
    Event.$emit("fetchdata");
  }
}
```

In your other component, mounted property should be like below:

```
mounted() {
  Event.$on("fetchdata", group => {
    this.fetchData();
 });
},
methods() {
  function fetchData() {
     console.log('hoooray :)');
  }
},
```